# VS2010 complaining about Microsoft.VisualBasic dependency

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I've got a .NET solution that I've just upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010. It contains three web projects and two straight VB projects. The web projects all depend on (and have a reference to) one of the VB projects called BusinessLogic.

All projects are targeted at .NET 2.0, but VS2010 is raising the following build warning:

> The following assembly has dependencies on a version of the .NET
>   Framework that is higher than the target and might not load correctly
>   during runtime causing a failure: BusinessLogic,
>   Version=1.0.4419.22315, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. The
>   dependencies are: Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. You should either
>   ensure that the dependent assembly is correct for the target
>   framework, or ensure that the target framework you are addressing is
>   that of the dependent assembly.

As far as I understand 8.0.0.0 is the correct version of VB for .NET 2.0, so why is this a warning? Is this something to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to menu Project|Properties and check the "References" Tab.
Check if the References you use are .NET 2.0 or higher.